# Cannot build app due to AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, android-manifest

When I try to run my code I end up with these errors.I tried to change the values to true but every time I rebuild it, it got deleted. Any suggestions?
Thank you!

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ninepinnapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="24"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:testOnly="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ninepinnapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: android:fullBackupContent="" remove that

Comment: If the error log can be expressed in text format according to the guide of Stack Overflow, it should be written in text. Not an image, can you read the guide below and correct your question? [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`android:fullBackupContent` can't be empty. Set it to `true` or `false`

Comment: My problem is that after I modify the blank space with "true" and run it, it deletes it and looks like that.

Comment: add `android:allowBackup="true"`